# I am trying to pass the output of a function (which is a path) to the next code .Please look below for the details

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, function, opencv

Hi Please look at the code I am trying to execute ,

But its showing 'my file' (the path) is not  defined' .Could someone help ?

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import os
import sys
import time

outputDir = (r"C:\Users\Ramesh\Desktop\Parsing_Project\Resumes")


def convert(file, outputDir):
    outputDir = outputDir + str(round(time.time())) + '/'
    if not os.path.exists(outputDir):
        os.makedirs(outputDir)

    pages = convert_from_path(file, 500)
    counter = 1
    for page in pages:
        myfile = outputDir +'output' + str(counter) +'.jpg'
        counter = counter + 1
        page.save(myfile, "JPEG")
        print(myfile)


file = (r'C:\Users\Ramesh\Desktop\Parsing_Project\Resumes_pdf\Sakshi Dixit.pdf')
convert(file, outputDir)

import cv2

import numpy as np

import pytesseract
import threading


image = cv2.imread(myfile)
```

'myfile' is supposed to pass the path for the image, But its saying its not defined
[image: This is the error screenshot]

Comment: Change line --
 file = (r'C:\Users\Ramesh\Desktop\Parsing_Project\Resumes_pdf\Sakshi Dixit.pdf')
to --
myfile = (r'C:\Users\Ramesh\Desktop\Parsing_Project\Resumes_pdf\Sakshi Dixit.pdf')

Comment: Hi @krishnareddy [ file = (r'C:\Users\Ramesh\Desktop\Parsing_Project\Resumes_pdf\Sakshi Dixit.pdf')] is my input file .I am converting it into image using pdf2image. After that I am saving the file in newly created folder and that new path is given as 'myfile' . While executing the function , you can see in the screenshot that its printing the new location of the output image file. I need to pass that new location to opencv. Thats what I am trying to do

Comment: `image = cv2.imread(myfile)`, the variable `myfile` exists only inside the function; you need to return from the function!

Comment: return myfile from convert function and edit fucntion call to - 
myfile = convert(file, outputDir).
I believe that you need to return a list of myfiles and iterate through each to get image.